# How do I clear a particular field in json having similar feilds in sub jsons using batch file?

Tags: json, batch-file, batch-rename

I want the password fields to be set as blank for only user1 when I run a batch script in my config.json.

`config.json` contains the following data

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": "user1",
    "password": "Password" 
  },
  "data2":{    
    "user": "user2",
    "password": "Password2"
  }
}
```

Any idea how to do it?

Actually I am new to batch script but I am able to change all the password fields

Comment: take a look at [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) to process JSON sources

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74457179.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

CALL :zapflags 
SET "indent=    "

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "repro=y"
 FOR %%y IN (%%e) DO IF DEFINED fpass (
  SET "repro="
  CALL :zapflags 
  ECHO %indent%"password": ""
 ) ELSE (
  IF DEFINED fuser1 IF %%y=="password": (SET "fpass=y"&SET "fuser=") ELSE (CALL :zapflags) 
  IF DEFINED fuser IF %%~y==user1 (SET "fuser1=y") ELSE (CALL :zapflags) 
  IF %%y=="user": SET "fuser=y"
 )
 IF DEFINED repro ECHO %%e
)
)>"%outfile%"

TYPE "%outfile%"

GOTO :eof

:zapflags 

FOR %%z IN (fuser fuser1 fpass) DO SET "%%z=")

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Read each line of the file to `%%e`, noting that the flags `fuser`,`fuser1` and `fpass` have all been cleared (made undefined)

Either we are going to simply reproduce the line as-is or we are going to replace it. The flag `repro` is set to `y` (any value) to indicate `reproduce this line`.

Analyse the substrings in each line. Substrings are separated by commas or spaces.

if the substring `"user":` appears, set the flag `fuser`.
if the substring `user1` appears next, set the flag `fuser1`, otherwise clear the f* flags
if the substring `"password":` appears next, set the flag `fpass` and clear the flag `fuser`, otherwise clear the f* flags
The password following should be skipped and replaced with an empty string, so clear the `repro` flag to prevent the original line from being reproduced, clear the f* flags and echo the replacement line